# Installing driver from custom file

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, autorun

I recently began reading about the [autorun.inf entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Microsoft's website.

I read the section about **[DeviceInstall]**. It seems to give the 'device' being inserted the capability to install its own driver.

I tried it, but still Windows is automatically installing its own drivers instead of searching for the drivers specified in the autorun.inf

Is the **[DeviceInstall]** entry still allowed for external hard drives under Windows 7? What are the entries allowed in the autorun.inf under Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is incorrect. The [MSDN article on **Creating an AutoRun-Enabled Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144206(v=vs.85).aspx#deviceinstall) says:

> You use [**`DriverPath`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx#DeviceInstall_Commands) to specify a directory path where Windows XP searches for driver files, which prevents a lengthy search through the entire contents.
>
> You use the **`[DeviceInstall]`** section with a driver installation to specify directories where Windows XP should search the media for driver files. Under Windows XP, entire media are no longer searched by default, therefore requiring **`[DeviceInstall]`** to specify search locations.

What this means is that using the `DriverPath` command in the `DeviceInstall` section of the Autorun.inf file, you can only let Windows know **where to look for drivers** on a driver installation media.

It doesn't say anything about giving you permission to force installation of an unsupported or invalid driver. If Windows can't find a valid device driver in the path specified by `DriverPath`, it'll start looking elsewhere and maybe install a generic driver (if available).

To answer your second question, I'll quote this line from the MSDN article you linked with the question:

> The **`[DeviceInstall]`** section is only supported under Windows XP